# UWP System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object

Tags: uwp

I have an UWP App targeting the FCU. Since today I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.String'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.
   at MoneyFox.Windows.Views.AccountListView.AccountListView_obj1_Bindings.Update_CurrentBalance(Double obj, Int32 phase)
   at MoneyFox.Windows.
```

As far as I can see it happens as soon as a binding with the type double to a TextBlock should update. But I haven't changed anything on that code.

I have the latest VS 15.7.3. Also I made tries with targeting different platforms and different versions of Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform (currently 6.0.8).

The Link to the repository: https://github.com/NPadrutt/MoneyFox.Windows/tree/XamarinFormsNew

What can that be?

Comment: I found the issue.. I have a converter who implements IValueConverter by Xamarin.Forms as well as inherits from MvxValueConverter and I didn't set the convert method to Override. It seems that caused the issue.

Comment: Good point. I added an answer and some code to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue.. I have a converter who implements IValueConverter by Xamarin.Forms as well as inherits from MvxValueConverter so I can use it for Xamarin Forms Bindings aswell as with my UWP app withouth XF.

```
public class AmountFormatConverter : MvxValueConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Converter Logic
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    {
        // Convert Back Logic
    }
}
```

My issue here was, that I didn't set the the Override keyword for the implemented methods. It seems that caused the issue.

```
public class AmountFormatConverter : MvxValueConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Converter Logic
    }

    public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    {
        // Convert Back Logic
    }
}
```